# Want to make a custom design in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

**Use image link to understand the structure** I want to create a structure in "XAML".In which above we have phases and each phases we have activities.Like suppose for **planing** is a phase under which we have created an activity "Header Design",for **Pending** is a phase under which we  have created an activity "B".
So after saving all this how can i make my below structure i.e in xaml which control or way is there to bind activities in there phases only.
Need to make below structure.Please check the image at  below url:[Need to make Required Image.Click here!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0w_0wIBvXogWUQ2VzdpYkRSbGM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your description of problem is not clear. Can you please describe it better?

Comment: @yo yo : i want to handle the design basically like i  have saved any item below planing div right.now how could the control know that the which item should be placed under which Phase.are you able to understand.Please open the image link too it makes you understand better

Comment: I really don't understand. You have to specify it in clear way. Sorry

Comment: np @YoYo , i have two lists one for binding phases and one for binding activities of phases. i just want , the particular activity must be bind or shown under the particular phase to which activity is belong to. right now, all activities are binding under first phase by default.  i am using WPF.

Comment: Do you mean you want a master-detail view or do you want to have two different filtered lists that are based on the same list? If it is the later you should look at `BLinq`, `CLinq`, `OLinq`, `ReactiveUI`. These all are quite good for creating observable lists with linq in them.

Comment: You could define `ListView`s in your control with `DataTemplate` to achieve unified look, then bind the lists to the same observable collection and apply Filter according to the info you need to display i.e. view.Filter = i => (myType)i.Stage == Planning (where Planning is enum). HTH

Comment: Thanks,@XAMlMAX do you have a small demo for this because we are beginners in this

Comment: Give us a half hour and I'll make one for you. It won't look as good as the picture you have in your Qestion, but it will give you an idea.

Comment: Really helpful i just need an idea @XAMlMAX thanks,I am waiting for your demo.

Answer (score 1):

As we spoke before here is a little sample:

```
<DockPanel>
        <ListView Name="Planning">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Planning">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Background="Red">
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Text="Name of the Activity" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Text="Starting Date"/>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Text="Ending Date"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView Name="Pending"></ListView>
        <ListView Name="Ongoing"></ListView>
        <ListView Name="Check"></ListView>
        <ListView Name="Done"></ListView>
    </DockPanel>
```

There are couple of things you should consider
1. First instead of defining `CellTemplate` use `HeaderContainerStyle` and then apply it to your List.
2. You can ignore the names of the List they are only for reference.
3. Depending on what you use in your `DataTemplate` I would recommend using `Styles` to unify the look of each `Activity`.
**Assumptions**
I assumed that you know about `INotifyPropertyChanged` and how to implement it,
also that you know about MvvM pattern, Binding (you should use `ItemsSource` in this case),
when you bind your `ObservableCollection` you need to use this bit of code

```
var view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CurrentListView.ItemsSource);
```

If you get stuck somewhere just give us a shout and I'll try to help you.
Reason why I haven't posted ready solution is because it will be good experience for you developing this sort of application.

[MvvM Tutorial - Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute)
[Styles and templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872530/why-define-a-template-inside-a-style-in-xaml-wpf)

Comment: @XAMIMAX thanks a lot for providing us code.we are reviewing it and try to implement in our code